# WebBrowser control c# Scrollbars

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webbrowser control in my windows form application that output a dynamic HTML page. Now this webbrowser have a width and a height . When the page exceeds width of webbrowser scrollbars appear. How can I keep scrollbar to bottom of webbrowser?

What I try :

In that dynamical HTML page I put jQuery 1.8.1 and another script call scrollTo. I create another div to stand at the bottom of page (I use CSS). But it's doesn't work because of webbrowser ...

I know there are many scripts for doing that but none that works in my situation.
I have a div called "content" that hasn't a specified width and height and with .append() jQuery function it increases its height (its content).

How can I keep vertical scrollbar bottom of webbrowser in C# (I use VS 2010)?

Answer (score 1):

just give your div a style `overflow-y: scroll` to force a scrollbar.

Comment: actually overflow-x for a horizonal scrollbar

Comment: I don't want to force a scrollbar ... I just want to keep webbrowser control scrollbar bottom of page .